# x is in the interior of A iff distance between x and complement of A is positive.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve a problem from Mendelsons Introduction to Topology.
Note* C(A) is the complement of A, and Int(A) is the interior or the largest open set contained in A.

x ∈ Int (A) if and only if d(x, C(A)) > 0

Shouldn't it be d(c,Int(C(A))>0?

Otherwise if A is an open interval, then C(A) contains the limit points of A. But then the distance between the limit points are in the closure of A so the distance is zero as shown in part a. If it were Int(C(A)) it couldn't contain the limit points of A.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $C(A)$ is supposed to be the complement of $A$? Assuming this is the case, your "limit points" of the interval are not in Int($A$), so the distance can be 0.

Comment: Yes C(A) is the complement. So you agree that the statement I'm being asked to prove is incorrect?

Comment: No, I'm saying the statement is correct; your counterexample doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take any x in int(A) (open set), by definition exists a neighborhood V of x such that V don't have any point of C(A). If you assume that V is a open ball it's easy to show that the distance between x and C(A) is positive

Answer (score 0):

$C(A)$ is the complement of $A$ in this book.  I think referring to exercise 8 on page 52, will help; letting $x\in X$ with $A \subset X$, $d(x,A)=0$ if and only if every nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A$.  Likewise, $d(x,C(A))=0$ if and only if every nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $C(A)$. Choosing an $x$ that has distance zero to $C(A)$ relies on choosing a boundary point.  Note that $\textrm{Bdry}(A) = \overline{A} \bigcap \overline{C(A)}. $

Finally, Thm. 4.13 states that Int $(A) = C(\overline{C(A)})$.  If  $d(x,C(A))=0$, then $x\in \overline{C(A)} $, so $x\not\in C(\overline{C(A)}) $.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought d(x,C(A)) = inf{d(x,a)|a∈C(A)}? It's defined as the greatest lower bound of the set containing the distances between x and every point in C(A). So if C(A) does contain the limit points of A, which is possible, then infimum of all the distances is zero because C(A) contains an element from the closure of A. So this serves as a counter example, because it is supposedly true for ANY subset A of X?